# Identify unique folders that contain images in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, search

I would like to find all unique folders that contain images (.jpg, etc.) on my Windows 10 pc. I haven't been able to determine if I can modify the Windows 10 search features to limit the results to just one occurence of each folder that contains an image.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by running the following in powershell (as admin):

```
$type = "*.jpg"
dir c:\$type -Recurse | Select Directory -Unique | sort Directory
```

This will search the entire C: drive for all file extensions that are .jpg and then list the directories in a unique, alphabetical list. If you wanted this list in a .csv file, you could do the following:

```
$type = "*.jpg"
dir c:\$type -Recurse | Select Directory -Unique | sort Directory | export-csv c:\users\ralf\desktop\All_JPGs.csv
```